# How to redirect to root when action could not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users_controller with only show action.

When I go to 0.0.0.0:3000/users/ I get

```
Unknown action
The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController
```

I don't need to list all users. How can I redirect to root path if action's not found?

I guess it should be something like this

```
get '*path' => redirect('/')
```

or I should add

```
  def index
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

ps I'm using devise

**up**

I tried

```
 rescue_from AbstractController::ActionNotFound do
   redirect_to root_url
 end
```

as in console it shows

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController):
```

but it doesn't redirect me

**up2**

if it matters I have

```
  devise_for :users, path_names:{sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
  resources :users, only: [:show]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rescue_from` was broken in rails 3. not sure if it was fixed in later releases

Use the following solution

In your `routes.rb`, add the following line in the end of the file

```
match "*path", :to => "application#handle_404"
```

This basically means, any path that is not defined in your route will end up going to `handle_404` in aplication controller. Its very important to put this at the end of your file

And in your `ApplicationController`, add

```
def handle_404
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: It works only for something like localhost:3000/qweqweqwe but when I go to localhost:3000/users I still get the same error action not found