# How can I bypass error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

That's my files:

*routes.rb*

```
...
resources :users
...
```

*users_controller.rb*

```
...
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
...
```

*show.html.erb*

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
...
```

For example, I haven't user with 'id'=20.

Of course, if go to **users/20** it will be ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

I tried `@user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])`. But it's not good idea, because of ERB

I would like to redirect to root_url and make flash[:danger] for example.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: "But it's not good idea, because of ERB" - huh? I don't see how this has anything to do with ERB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to root when action could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639420/how-to-redirect-to-root-when-action-could-not-be-found)

Comment: @mrzasa: wrong dup target. Here action clearly exists.

Comment: Retracted the vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the generic `rescue_from`, something like this would allow you to handle different actions in one controller in different ways.

```
def show
  unless @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
    flash[:danger] = "watch out"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That's I wanted to do

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rescue_from](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) for this case. It's a pretty common approach

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: -> { render status: :not_found, nothing: true }
```

You might like to render 404 or make a redirect

Comment: This is what we actually do. You should render 404 not found page

Comment: @DeepakMahakale In that case you shouldn't rescue *ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound* since it will render *public/404.html* in production.